# Java type cannot be resolved MIME type class

Tags: java

I know this is a common question asked but I've been searching and I've included the class into eclipse through the buildpath. I start to write the import statement and it autocompletes options for me so I know it's finding the class.

My problem is how come it's giving this error when I'm reading the docs and it says the constructor method is MimeUtil2() ?

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/eu/medsea/mimeutil/mime-util/2.1/mime-util-2.1-javadoc.jar!/eu/medsea/mimeutil/MimeUtil2.html#MimeUtil2()

```
package com.jab.app;

import java.io.File;
import eu.medsea.mimeutil.*;

public class CheckFileType {

private void GetMimeType(File filename){

        MimeUtil2 test = new MimeUtil2();  //Produces the error saying java type cannot be resolved

}
```

Comment: your imports wrong. do this `import eu.medsea.mimeutil.MimeUtil2;` or `import eu.medsea.mimeutil.*;`

Comment: I tried that as well it does not work same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that I was using the test-source.jar not the main jar file itself. The sourceforge page made the default as the source file instead of the main jar file.
It was buried inside of the files page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to import

```
import eu.medsea.mimeutil.*;
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/eu/medsea/mimeutil/mime-util/2.1/mime-util-2.1-javadoc.jar!/eu/medsea/mimeutil/MimeUtil2.html), the type is `eu.medsea.mimeutil.MimeUtil2`

Comment: Did you get a different error?  Did you get the same error?  `It did not work` is *never* a valid explanation for anything, it tells absolutely nothing.

Comment: I really don't know.  If you have the right import(s), and you've properly imported the library in your project, then I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be working.  Can you make sure you have imported all the libraries you need, and you have imported them correctly?

Comment: Here is my code base maybe there's something I'm missing. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19220253/findduplicatefiles.zip

Comment: I ended up finding out that I was using the source.jar not the jar file itself. The sourceforge page made the default as the source file instead of the main jar file.

Frustrating to think they did that. But I learned something in the process.